# Use Cocos2d Within a Single iPhone View

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I have an iPhone application that is mostly using standard controls. There is one view that is rendered in OpenGL (fancy graphs). In the interest of saving myself a lot of work, I looked around and found Cocos2d. It looks like it has exactly what I need (OpenGL ES, relatively simple to work with), but I've run into a problem.

I don't know how to limit Cocos2d to exist in just a single view. Before, I implemented my OpenGL stuff in a view and used a simple ViewController to present it within a navigation controller. Here, Cocos2d seems to need to do a lot more, and I'm unsure how to stuff it into the same ViewController/View approach I did with raw OpenGL.

**UPDATE: This is what I *was* doing. Flip to the next bold to see what I'm doing now.**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CocosController : UIViewController {
    UIWindow *window;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

And my CocosController.m:

```
#import "CocosController.h"
#import "SomeScene.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"

@implementation CocosController

@synthesize window;

// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
    // Initialization code
    CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    //landscape
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [director setDisplayFPS:true];

    //turn on multi-touch
    EAGLView *cocosView = [director openGLView];
    [cocosView setMultipleTouchEnabled:true];

    self.view = cocosView;

    //default texture formats...
    [CCTexture2D  setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[SomeScene scene]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

And, finally, how I'm trying to present it (in a button click):

```
CocosController *cocosController = [[CocosController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:cocosController animated:true];
```

**This is the new approach, same results though.**

ApplicationDidFinish portion of my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeThreadMainLoop];

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];

    state = kStateEnd;

    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

CocosController I'm using to present the view:

```
#import "CocosController.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "SomeScene.h"

@implementation CocosController

@synthesize mainView;

// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
    EAGLView *glview = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250,350)];
    [mainView addSubview:glview];

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [director setOpenGLView:glview];

    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    id node = [SomeScene node];
    [scene addChild: node];

    [director runWithScene:scene];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And this bit is from a button click in a details ViewController I have that is supposed to make this whole thing appear:

```
CocosController *cc = [[CocosController alloc]init];
cc.mainView = self.view;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:cc animated:false];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float row = (a % itemsPerRow) * texStepX;
```

The above line of code was where the app was crashing every time I tried another way to get the view running. I finally just tried to look it up, thinking I wouldn't find anything. Turns out, cocos2d makes an assumption that an image, fps_images.png, is assumed to be in the project. If it's not, this particular bit of cocos2d explodes with an arithmetic exception.

Took two seconds to fix by just finding fps_images.png in the cocos2d directory and adding it to the Resources folder of my project.

*sigh*

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing seems overkill. `CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();` is used to initialize a view and a `CCDirector`, and is recommended where you'll be attaching cocos2d to the main view.

If you take a look at the sample provided in Cocos2d, called `AttachTest` (see the file `attachDemo.m`) you can see how to attach a `CCDirector` to any view. Here's the code the sample uses:

```
EAGLView *glview = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250,350)];
[mainView addSubview:glview];

CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director setOpenGLView:glview];
```

In this snippet, a new `EAGLView` is created, and then is set as the `openGLView` of the `CCDirector`.

My suggestion is that you create your view controller and and empty view as usual (maybe using Interface Builder, or the code above), and then, in the `loadView` method attach the `CCDirector` to that view.

Comment: Okay, I've implemented what the AttachTest demo was doing, but when I call "[director setOpenGLView:glview];" (after creating the EAGLView and adding that as a subview), it crashes. Specifically, line 75 of CCLabelAtlas (the variable texStepX is null). This is the same behavior I was getting before, which leads me to think I'm just not initializing something properly.

Comment: Correction: texStepX is infinite.